# NgZorro Autocomplete Selectbox can't be populated without selecting something before

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, populate, ng-zorro-antd

I am not sure if this is a bug or wrong implementation on my side.

I try to populate an autocomplete selectbox with `AutocompleteDataSourceItem`.
The `AutocompleteDatasourceItem` contains `label` and `value`.

If I use the following code on a fresh initialized form field the form is correctly populated as I check the value of the field in the debugger but the field on the form shows `[object Object]`:

```
this.form.controls.baseIngredient.setValue(this.baseIngredientOptions.filter(x => x.value == 11)[0]);
```

If I manually select something then use the same code the field is properly populated.
Can anyone help me qith that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

`this.form.get('baseIngredient').setValue(this.baseIngredientOptions.find(x => x.value === 11).value;`

The problem is you're trying to set {key:string,value:string} but you must give the value as value, not the object.

In your code, here is how you can achieve;

`this.form.controls.baseIngredient.setValue(this.baseIngredientOptions.filter(x => x.value == 11)[0].value);`

But this is not a good code in my opinion. you should use the first one. Both will do the trick i believe.